# Why can't I sort AND deduplicate my Array?

Tags: javascript

Without the `if(a !== b)...` it sorts the numbers fine; which I totally get however I got it in my head that I should be able to de-dupe the numbers with a conditional `if statement`, but it won't work.

Why doesn't this way of solving this problem work?

```js
const myArr = [1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 5, 2, 2, 19, 11, 7]

const newArr = myArr.sort(sortFn)

function sortFn (a, b){
  if(a !== b){ 
  // Shouldn't 'if' allow me to remove duplicates?
    return a-b
  } 
}
//working function: this one does the sort as per usual
/* 
function sortFn (a, b){
    return a-b
}
*/
```

Comment: `Shouldn't 'if' allow me to remove duplicates?` no ... `.sort` doesn't `.filter` it `.sort`s

Comment: `Array.from(new Set(myArr)).sort((a, b) => a - b)`

Comment: The `.sort()` method absolutely will never remove elements from your array. Sort first then remove duplicates in a second pass.

Comment: @JaromandaX sure, whatever; doing it after sorting may be easier because the duplicates might be all right next to each other

Comment: since OP uses `const` then likely to have `Set` - that's why I mentioned the other way around :p

Comment: @JaromandaX oh right, good point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldn't 'if' allow me to remove duplicates?

No, sorting will not remove elements ever.  It just changes the order.

Calling map(...) or forEach(...) will do the same: 1 to 1 in respect to the array's elements.

Only filter(...) and reduce(...) will iterate and modify the number of items in the returned array.

BTW here's your filter function:

```
function unique (value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

myArray.sort(sortFunction).filter(unique)
```

Comment: `filter` or `slice` can return arrays different to the original, there's also `splice` that can mutate an array "in place" - map returns 1:1 .. forEach returns undefined

Comment: Thank you Steven.

Answer (score 2):

Using if wont remove duplicates from array, use filter instead,

DEMO

```js
const myArr = [1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 5, 2, 2, 19, 11, 7]

const newArr = myArr.sort(sortFn).filter((v,i) => myArr.indexOf(v) == i)
console.log(newArr);
function sortFn (a, b){  
   return a-b
  
}
```

Comment: Fast Responses!
BUT this is the question: "Why doesn't this way of solving this problem work?"...WHY WHY. That's what I'm angling for. Sorry if that's not clear.

Comment: Because you are sorting only if the condition is met, condition and removing duplicates are two different things

Comment: you've been told **why** @misterhtmlcss - because `sort` sorts, `filter` filters, `map` maps, `find` finds, `slice` slices, `splice` splices, `fill` fills - can you see the pattern?

Comment: But I'm using a callback, so that function can do what it does and then the sort sorts what remains. That's why I was curious why it wouldn't work. I was hoping for a detailed technical response (like a step through) so that I could understand why it's broken versus 'sort sort' 'filter filter', etc.

Comment: the answer is not to be detailed as far as i think because it is self explanatory.

Comment: `detailed technical response` - *sort sorts an array* ... what part  of `sort` implies *removes elements according to your whim* ?

Answer (score 0):

The [compare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function passed to sort, does not do what you think it does.

The compare function, returns for each item, a negative number if a < b , a positive if a > b,and  0 if a == b.
If you don't return anything, then it will be interpreted as 0, i.e. both elements are the same, and as such need no internal reordering needed.

The compare function does no other work, in sorting than telling the sort algorithm the relationship between the two elements being compared.